# Diff inside if-statement condition - how to make it true?

Tags: bash, if-statement, diff

I have

`diff <file1> <file2>` which returns nothing

I want it inside condition which is true when diff returns nothing. I tried it in several ways, but all the time I had else-commands executed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to check if two files are equal, you can check the exit code of `diff -q` (or `cmp`). This is faster since it doesn't require finding the exact differences:

```
if diff -q file1 file2 > /dev/null
then
  echo "The files are equal"
else
  echo "The files are different or inaccessible"
fi
```

All Unix tools have an exit code, and it's usually faster, easier and more robust to check that than to capture and compare their output in a text-based way.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the logic pipe:

For one command:

```
diff -q file1 file2 > /dev/null && echo "The files are equal"
```

Or more commands:

```
diff -q file1 file2 > /dev/null && {
    echo "The files are equal"; echo "Other command"
    echo "More other command"
}
```